# What is user_activation_key in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress and wish to know what is the `user_activation_key` in the `wp_users` table? It's like a string of digit with an encrypted code (similar to the password). Why some of the user do not have one.

Comment: I think it is only created if a user gets sent an email upon creation or when they request a password reset.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal You mean after the user create the account or reset the password (each reset will generate a new one?), it will no longer be used. Does it have any additional use?

Comment: Well, am not sure about the additional use. Yes, whenever a user reset the password this key gets generated or say whenever user reset and gets mail.

Answer (score 42):

`user_activation_key` is one of those keys that WordPress uses for authenticity of a **Reset Password** request.

So, when you are saying this key is empty for some users, the reason is, those users have never requested for a password reset.

When a password reset is requested a temporary key is generated called `check_password_reset_key` and sent via email for the reset process.

When the user goes to the generated link, this key is directly compared with `user_activation_key`. If both keys don't match then it is considered to be an **Invalid Request**. Otherwise it proceeds and the user will be allowed to enter a new password for his account.

If you want to understand how it works with more details, you can check the [wordpress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/check_password_reset_key/).

Comment: This response is _dangerous_ because it omits the fact, that after a _successful_ reset, that database value _is emptied  again_. So - you can NOT define if a user NEVER reset their password by the mere fact of that value being empty. They MIGHT have very well reset it, successfully. At which point WP will clear that value again.

Comment: @user3934058: it sounds sensible for the `user_activation_key` field to be wiped on a successful reset, but I have a WP installation where this is not happening. Have you looked in the source code to see what's supposed to happen? (I haven't done so yet myself.)(Edit: caveat: I suppose the other option is that users remembered their passwords after requesting a reset, and thus the field was never wiped... hmm)

Comment: doh, ran out of time to edit previous comment: The source code _does_ suggest that the field is wiped when a new password is set.